# Problem with paracol: a particular use of "switchcolumn" differentiates column width

Tags: paracol

Please take a look at the following code and its output: The use of `switchcolumn` before `itemize` widens the column width (compared to the itemize1 sentence).

For some reasons, I need to keep on using this syntax and want to eliminate this difference. Is there any solution?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item {} 
    enumerate sentence

    \begin{itemize}
        \item {} 
        subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1
    \end{itemize}

    \switchcolumn

interfering text

    \switchcolumn

    \begin{itemize}
        \item {} 
        subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2
    \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put `parccol` inside `enumerate` ?

Answer (score 1):

Paracol keeps duplicates of counters, but not lengths.  This is a Q&D solution.  There are LOTS of lengths used by lists (`\leftmargin`, `\totalleftmargin`, `\rightmargin`) which might need duplkicate values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{paracol}

\newlength{\savewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item {} 
    enumerate sentence

    \begin{itemize}
        \item {} 
        subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1 subitemize1
    \end{itemize}
\savewidth=\linewidth
    \switchcolumn

interfering text

    \switchcolumn
\linewidth=\savewidth

    \begin{itemize}
        \item {} 
        subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2 subitemize2
    \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```